# Jquery - Edit text to a number of an element

Tags: jquery, html

I've been working on this bug for like 2 hours now and it's driving me crazy.

What i am trying to do is getting a number from an element (which works) and change the number and replace it with the previous number. But the number gets replaced with a string, and the previous number remains.

HTML:

```
<span class="likesAmount">1</span>
```

JQuery:

```
  //get number
  Likes = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('.likesAmount').text());
  //replace number
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.likesAmount').text(Likes = (Likes - 1 == -1 ? Likes = 0 : Likes - 1));
```

I tried things such as, html, data, parsing it to an int with text etc..

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sorry guys, i forgot to use my commen sence it was getting into the likes twice that was causing incorrect results.. This code has nothing to do with it. But thanks for helping me though!

Comment: Show more of your html, maybe element is not selected properly.

Comment: wait, you're trying to decrease the amount of `Likes`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that finding the element works, your code looks like it should work. Splitting it out might help diagnose the problem:

```
var element = $(this).parent().parent().find('.likesAmount');
var likes = parseInt(element.text(), 10);
element.text( Math.max(likes - 1, 0) );
```

Comment: +1. I was just about to post the same idea with `Math.max(likes - 1, 0)`. But even using something like `likes > 0 ? likes - 1 : 0` would be less confusing than the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//get number
Likes = parseInt($('.likesAmount').text());
//replace number
$('.likesAmount').text(Likes);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, here is the solution I came up with:

```
//get number
var Likes = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('.likesAmount').text());
if((Likes - 1) === -1) {
  Likes = 0;
}
else {
  Likes = 1;
}
  //replace number
$(this).parent().parent().find('.likesAmount').text(String(Likes));
```

I took the if/else logic out of the text assignment. I then converted `Likes` to a String when inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i made a dumb mistake. The code was indeed correct, but i forgot a simple if, it was getting into the + 1 twice.. That was my mistake, thanks for the answers!